# Cache UIImage using uitableview from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching, uiimage

I hava a uitableview , with custom cell containing two UImages. The logo images are taken from an online website, that's why there's a need to cache the images. Loading the image till now is made like this :

```
 NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arra1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row / 2]];
 NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

 NSURL * imageURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[arra2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row / 2]];
 NSData * imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2];

 cell.ima1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 cell.ima2.image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];
```

What i learned from searching , is that dataWithContentsOfURL is not asynchronous , and while scrolling it will take a lot of time. I tried several methods but i can't seem to get to right one. This is my first time caching UIImages , i would highly appreciate a detailed explanation with implementation so i could learn aside from getting the job done.
Many Thanks

Comment: to Cache UIImage use SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @JayGajjar thank you for your reply , i tried it but i got lost, i'm really new, can you please show me an implementation ?

Comment: its simple just use setImageWithURL with your uiimageview. Rest will be managed by the sdk.

Comment: i tried it, @JayGajjar but still the uitableview scrolling is really bad and extremely slow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this Library which is just perfect

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: i couldn't thank you enough!! before i trie the SDWebImage , but i failed to implement it correctly, so the results were messy.. the secret of this method if with the placeHolderImage !!! DO NOT DELETE IT ever, that was the difference between what i had been trying all day and what @Erid suggested…Thank you and this is for all future developers to take under consideration,...

Answer (score 1):

`SDWebImage`, in my opinion, is the best option.

You simply include it in your app and use it like this:

- ```
  SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

  [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image_url]
                   options:0
                  progress:nil
                 completed:^(UIImage *images, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL complete) {

                     myImageView.image = images;
                 }] ;
  ```

It download images asynchronously, so it does not block UI.

Comment: using it still holds up the tableview and still it takes too long to scroll :S what am i missing

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath should i add it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can check these sample application

1. [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) - Sample application from Apple
2. [MonoTouch-LazyTableImages](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/LazyTableImages)
3. [robertmryan- LazyTableImages](https://github.com/robertmryan/LazyTableImages) - Explains clearly the limitations from apple's sample application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout UIImageLoader https://github.com/gngrwzrd/UIImageLoader

Easy to load an image, and you get callbacks for all the scenarios you would want to handle:

```
NSURL * imageURL = myURL;   

[[UIImageLoader defaultLoader] loadImageWithURL:imageURL \

hasCache:^(UIImage *image, UIImageLoadSource loadedFromSource) {

    //there was a cached image available. use that.
    self.imageView.image = image;

} sendRequest:^(BOOL didHaveCachedImage) {

    //a request is being made for the image.

    if(!didHaveCachedImage) {
        //there was not a cached image available, set a placeholder or do nothing.

        self.loader.hidden = FALSE;
        [self.loader startAnimating];

        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
    }

} requestCompleted:^(NSError *error, UIImage *image, UIImageLoadSource loadedFromSource) {

    //network request finished.

    [self.loader stopAnimating];
    self.loader.hidden = TRUE;

    if(loadedFromSource == UIImageLoadSourceNetworkToDisk) {
        //the image was downloaded and saved to disk.
        //since it was downloaded it has been updated since
        //last cached version, or is brand new

        self.imageView.image = image;
    }
}];
```